# Problem with encoding when clipping raster

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, encoding

I am using QGIS 2.18 on a Linux Mint computer using UTF8.
I downloaded [solar radiation raster data from PVGIS](http://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvg_download/solar_radiation_sarah_download.html). The files are encoded as us-ascii (according to the linux command tool *file -bi*).
Opening the data in QGIS works fine. But I want to clip this data to reduce it to the area of the project on which I work and here is the problem.

I created a .shp vector layer as the mask layer for clipping, and when I try clipping (Raster > Extraction > Clipper ) , I have the following Python error : `Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/GdalTools/tools/widgetPluginBase.py", line 88, in onFinished
self.base.onFinished(exitCode, status)
File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/GdalTools/tools/dialogBase.py", line 208, in onFinished
msg = unicode(self.process.readAllStandardError())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 52: ordinal not in range(128)`:

Obviously, it's something with the file encoding.
A quick search led me to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475393/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc3-in-position-23-ordinal#24475405) but that does not really help me solving the problem.

Comment: Was just trying to help a user with the exact same problem, did you figure this out?

Comment: No. I am stalling on this right now.